# Negation of this logical statment (p and q) -> r

Tags: logic

I've been messing around with trying to negate this statement using DeMorgans laws and I keep ending up with incorrect answers such as (~p or ~q) and ~r. If someone could help me with the negation of compound statements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple method to negate statements.

1. Rule: 
   Change implications to its disjunction form. $A\rightarrow B$ will be $\lnot A \lor B$
2. Rule: If you negate a bracket, you negate all the contents and change the logical connectives: $\lor$ will be $\land$ and $\land$ will be $\lor$.
3. Eliminate double negations and you're done.

Example: $\lnot ((\lnot p\lor q)\rightarrow \lnot s)$

1. $ \lnot(\lnot (\lnot p \lor q )\lor \lnot s)$
2. $ \lnot \lnot (\lnot p \lor q)\land \lnot \lnot s$
3. $(\lnot p \lor q)\land s$

Answer (score 0):

$x\implies y$ means $y$ or $\lnot x$.  Take $x=p$ and $q$.

$\lnot(p $ and $q)$ means $\lnot p $ or $ \lnot q$.

$\lnot(a $ or $b)$ means $\lnot a $ and $\lnot b$.

Comment: So how would you write the negation of (p and q)->r   ?

Comment: @Spencer Can you try to take it from here? The purpose of this site is to aid in the education process, not to hand out answers to problems

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now [(p^q)and ~r], does this mean I only have to change the later half of this equation?